# unusual behaviour of HashCode in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am stuck around while studying hashCode() in java.
I wrote a sample code PFB snippet

```
public class Shared {
    String type;
    Date date;
 public Shared(String type) {
    this.type = type;

 }

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.date = new Date(19894894823948L);
}

public static void main(String arg[]) {
    HashMap<Shared, String> hm = new HashMap<Shared, String>();
    Shared key = new Shared("me");
    Shared key1 = new Shared("me1");
    hm.put(key1, "value1");
    hm.put(key, "value");

    System.out.println(key.hashCode());//returning hashcode suppose X
    key.type=null;
    key.setType("type");
    System.out.println(key.hashCode());// it's even returning X again
    key.type="null";
    System.out.println(key.hashCode());// it's even returning X again.
```

}

I am really confused how this is possible even after changing the value contained within the key hashCode is same. it's literally breaking the immutable key concept.

Is the hashCode() method architecture/platform dependent?

Comment: Did you create `Shared` class? Did you override `hashCode()` and `equals()`?

Comment: How does the `HashMap` influence `hashCode()` generation of the `Shared` class? I suppose that you would get the same results without putting `key1` and `key` into a HashMap ...

Comment: It seems pretty likely that you're either overriding `hashCode` not to use `type`, or you're not overriding it at all... but we can't tell which when we can't see the code for `Shared.hashCode`. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: No I did not override hashCode or equals.

Comment: Well there we go then. It's behaving exactly as I'd expect.

Comment: It's simply not unique. Different keys can generate the same hash code. What happens is when searching for a key, it uses the generated hash code to get to a position in the table where it's LIKELY to be, but the keys are always compared. When they are not the same, the key is rehashed, using the same or different hash function ( with extra input like the current found position for another position and the process repeats.

Comment: @HansLepoeter: I don't think the OP ever mentioned an expectation of uniqueness...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Comment: I think so, he mentioned "it's even returning X again", so he expected a different one. Even with below answer, which adresses the main problem in the code, my comment is still valid. It's likely it's diffrent though when overriding hashCode, but it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am really confused how this is possible even after changing the value contained within the key hashCode is same. it's literally breaking the immutable key concept.

Nope, it's fine. You're not overriding `equals` or `hashCode`, so it's not using the value of the `type` field as part of the equality comparison... it's just using reference identity, effectively. `key` still refers to the same object as it did, so it's entirely sensible for it to return the same hash code. Nothing affecting the hash code or equality has changed.

If you want your `Shared` type to be useful as a key in a map, I'd suggest:

- Overriding `hashCode()` and `equals()`, making sure you obey all the relevant contracts
- Preventing instances from being mutated in equality-affecting ways
- Renaming it to be clearer about what it's meant to represent

> Is the hashCode() method architecture/platform dependent?

It's up to the implementation, basically. From the docs:

> As much as is reasonably practical, the `hashCode` method defined by class `Object` does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the Java™ programming language.)

It would be *valid* for the `Object.hashCode()` method to always return 0... it just wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet  I learnt a new this today.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't override `hashcode()` method in your class, you will get it from`Object`. this means that it will not look at any of your class's fields when calculating the hashcode, therefor re-setting the value of type does nothing.

You need to override the method and calculate all fields of your class.